# Magento 2 simple form submit

Tags: forms, magento-2.1, post-data

To understand the new magento 2 design structure i'm trying to create a simple frontend form submitting module. In it i'm submitting a number in an input box and i want to multiply it by 2 and display the result in another page. What is the correct architectural flow to achieve it? And please mention a link for a similar example if available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start by defining a route for your module. This is done in `<module_directory>/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="timestwo" frontName="timestwo">
            <module name="Your_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then make the 'Index' controller for this route under `<module_directory>/Controller/Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Make the layout file for this page under `<module_directory>/view/frontend/layout/timestwo_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="form" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Your_Module::form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now make the template `<module_directory>/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`

```
<form class="form" action="result" method="post">

    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test Form') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="number" class="label">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Input') ?></span>
            </label>

            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="number"
                       name="number"
                       class="input-text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Now make the controller for the result page: `<module_directory>/Controller/Result.php`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Result extends Action
{
    /** @var PageFactory $resultPageFactory */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Result constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * The controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $number = $this->getRequest()->getParam('number');

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        /** @var Messages $messageBlock */
        $messageBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages',
            'answer'
        );
        if (is_numeric($number)) {
            $messageBlock->addSuccess($number . ' times 2 is ' . ($number * 2));
        }else{
            $messageBlock->addError('You didn\'t enter a number!');
        }

        $resultPage->getLayout()->setChild(
            'content',
            $messageBlock->getNameInLayout(),
            'answer_alias'
        );

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Finally, make the layout xml for the result page in `<module_directory>/view/frontend/layout/timestwo_result.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to enable your module, if you haven't already.
Now clear the cache.
Go to `<magento_location>/timestwo` in browser to see the form.

Comment: Thanks alot i was stuck in this because i couldn't find  a proper tutorial

Comment: @AaronAllen I followed same thing, but I am getting 404 error. I have created the module registration and configurations also. Could you please help me.

Comment: Yes, I got it after creating the `Index` folder in `Controller`. I don't know why I am getting  404, if I use the above solution.

Comment: after adding index folder then rename layout file as timestwo_index_index.xml and timestwo_index_result.xml

Comment: I am getting 404 error after creating this.