# How to save/select a custom phml form in DB on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, controllers, model, forms

I have created a custom module, and i have this phtml:

```
<div class="container-club">
    <h2>test<h2>
    <div class="club-img">
    </div>
        <div class="club-login-field">
        <form>
            <div class="club-name field">
                <label class="" for="email"><span>Naam</span></label><br>
                <input type="input" name="club-name" id="club-name" class="input-text" >
            </div>
            <div class="club-email-address control">
                <label class="" for="email"><span>E-Mailadres</span></label><br>
                <input type="input" name="club-name" id="club-name" class="input-text"><br>
                <a class="action remind" href="#"><span>Wachtwoord vergeten?</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="club-login-button">
                <button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span>CLUBLOGIN INLOGGEN</span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

In this module i have already set a controller, block and i have created a custom table also.

My question:

How can i submit this form and insert/select this 2 fields into DB, via **Controller** or **Model**?

Does anyone can help me with some instructions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125027/magento-2-simple-form-submit ?